# How to use ModelicaError() function in a .dll (Dymola)

Tags: dll, modelica, dymola

I have a Modelica external C function that calls a function that is in a .dll.

In the C function in the .dll I would like to make use of the ModelicaError() function.   However when
#include ModelicaUtilities.h is included a number of errors occur.

What is the correct method for doing this?
I take it I'll need to link against an existing Dymola .lib, which one?  What should DYMOLA_STATIC be defined as?
Or should I be compiling the .dll in such a way that these missing functions will be available after compilation with the model?

Any insight into this would be great, Thanks

Comment: What errors do you get from including ModelicaUtilities.h? You should not get any errors until you reach the linking stage

Comment: If I don't define DYMOLA_STATIC then there is a long list of errors.
If I set this to DYNMOLA_STATIC as:
#define DYNMOLA_STATIC

then I get something that is solved by including dsutil.h.  However this introduces more errors that is solved by including dsblock.h, this introduces more errors which I've not been able to solve.  However basically I'm left feeling that I'm not going about this correctly.

Comment: ModelicaUtilities.h only contains the prototype for ModelicaError.  I'm guessing setting:
#define DYNMOLA_STATIC extern
is a good start however errors are still generated when trying to compile the dll because the ModelicaError function cannnot be found.

Comment: If generating a .lib you just set #define DYNMOLA_STATIC extern     and    #include ModelicaUtilities.h
when generating a dll this does not work.

Comment: This post explains the situation nicely:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174951/how-to-link-a-function-declared-as-extern-in-h-file-to-create-a-dll-file

So you need to provide pointers to the ModelicaError function.

Answer (score 2):

From all what I know it is currently not possible in a tool-independent way to have shared objects (DLLs on Win) depending on ModelicaError (or any other functions of ModelicaUtilities). See https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/2191 for the open issue on the Modelica Language specification.

Answer (score 0):

To use ModelicaError function in a dll you send the a pointer to the ModelicaError function.  To do this from Dymola create a wrapper function that passes the pointer to the ModelicaError function to the dll function.  For example MathLibraryWrapper:

```
#pragma once
#include "MathLibrary.h"
int fibonacci_next_int_wrap()
{
    return fibonacci_next_int(&ModelicaError);
}
```

This calls the fibonacci_next_int function which is in MathLibary.cpp in the dll.  This is modified to accept a pointer to the ModelicaError function.

```
int fibonacci_next_int(void(*mError)(const char *))
{
    (*mError)("broken");
    return (int)fibonacci_next();
}
```

If this is run it will immediately crash with "broken".